# Referring to a chain of hash keys in a Perl hash of hashes

Tags: perl, hash-of-hashes

I have a hash of hashes storing data like so

```
our %deviceSettings = (
  BB => {
          EUTRA => {
            DL => { CPC => "NORM", PLCI => { CID => 88 }, ULCPc => "NORM" },
            UL => {
                    REFSig  => { DSSHift => 2, GRPHopping => 1, SEQHopping => 1 },
                    SOFFset => 0,
                  },
          },
        },
  ...
);
```

I can walk the structure and find a particular key, say `CID`, and retrieve its value and store the 'path' in an array `('BB', 'EUTRA', 'DL', 'PLCI')`.

I can also explicitly set a value, like this

```
$deviceSettings_ref->{BB}{EUTRA}{DL}{PLCI}{CID} = 99
```

But I want to know how to set a value programatically using a discovered path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can walk up the hash using a placeholder `$hashref`:

```
my $hashref = \%deviceSettings;

$hashref = $hashref->{$_} for qw(BB EUTRA DL PLCI);
$hashref->{CID} = 'My New Path';

use Data::Dump;
dd \%deviceSettings;
```

Outputs:

```
{
  BB => {
          EUTRA => {
            DL => { CPC => "NORM", PLCI => { CID => "My New Path" }, ULCPc => "NORM" },
            UL => {
                    REFSig  => { DSSHift => 2, GRPHopping => 1, SEQHopping => 1 },
                    SOFFset => 0,
                  },
          },
        },
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Walking the hashref down the tree using a for loop (I used an array as input) is just what I needed. If anyone's interested this is what it looks like:
My hash walker runs a function when it finds a given key and passes it the key in $k, and a list of the path in @$key_list. For example $k = CID and @$key_list = ['BB', 'EUTRA', 'DL', 'PLCI', 'CID']
`
 pop @$key_list;
 my $hashref = \%deviceSettings;
 $hashref = $hashref->{$_} for (@$key_list);
 $hashref->{$k} = 'My New Value';
`
Very straight forward. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Data::Diver](http://p3rl.org/Data::Diver) is a module for accessing nested structures using paths.

```
use Data::Diver 'DiveVal';

my $device_settings_rf = {};
my @path = ( 'BB', 'EUTRA', 'DL', 'PLCI', 'CID' );
DiveVal( $device_settings_rf, \(@path) ) = 99;
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks like it would do what I needed, but the other answer uses built-in functionality which will be easier to deliver without the Data::Diver package.

Comment: ah, it wasn't clear from your original question that all the keys for any path you want already exist; Data::Diver is probably overkill then.

Comment: Should be `DiveVal( $device_settings_rf, map \$_, @path )` if any elements of `@path` could be a number